# How to check if a user has more than 5 failed logins and prevent brute force

Tags: php, mysql

I want to avoid users to have many failed logins and also to prevent attacks. If the number of failed logins are 5 or more then there will be a captcha or disable access for 15 mins.

Beloow you find my code on what happens when the user is successfully logged in or not. There is some code missing, I use sessions on correct login.

The number of failed logins can be found at false_logins column.

`$result` checks if `$login` and `$password` are found using a query.

Thank you for this.

```
$result=mysql_query($qry);
$member = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

//Check whether the query was successful or not and if user is verified. Verified users have empty value

if($result) {
    if ( (mysql_num_rows($result) == 1) && (!$member['verified']) ){

        //Login Successful
mysql_query("UPDATE members SET ip = '$ip', false_login = '0' WHERE login = '$login'");
        header("location: member-index.php");
        exit();

    }else {

        //Login failed
mysql_query("UPDATE members SET false_login = false_login+1 WHERE login = '$login'");
        header("location: login-failed.php");

        exit();
    }

}else {

    die("Query failed");
}
```

Comment: You're going to have to get the updated value of the false_login field at some point unless you change the code to store the number of login attempts in a cookie or session variable.

Comment: @Brent Friar: cookie or session solution will fail as long as bruteforcers barely keep session cookie or any cookie at all on login fail.

Comment: Based on that code, I could give you some trouble (by locking you out) just by knowing your $login.

Comment: @mmhan What are you suggesting?

Comment: Yes zerkms, I missed the brute force part of the question.

Comment: @Giorkouros - Let's say I know your login name, all I need to lock you out of your own system is to fail a login attempt a X number of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You better create a history of login fails table with `ip + date` columns. And see if in an interval there were more than N failed attempts from the same IP.

And if that happened - you could put captcha, as google does, for example.

Comment: @Giorkouros: what actually you cannot get or write?